# jquery show()/Hide() dynamically named elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to show/hide details with jquery about a specific event.  I am fairly new to jquery, so pardon my stupidness.  The events come from a database and are dynamically loaded.  For example I have an event with and eventID of 23.  I load the basic information about the event with two buttons below "Venue Info" and "Event Details".

The buttons have IDs like `23VenueBut` and `23EventBut`.  What I want to do is show the div with the ID of 23VenueDiv and 23EventDiv when the button is clicked and change the button to a different image that says Hide Details, etc and when clicked again hide the specified div.

```
<?php do { ?>
      <div id="scheduleMain"><?php if ($row_rsSchedules['Assoc1WebURL'] != "") { echo '<a href="'.$row_rsSchedules['Assoc1WebURL'].'">'; } ?><img src="images/schedules/<?php echo $row_rsSchedules['AssociationID']; ?>.png" border="0"><?php if ($row_rsSchedules['Assoc1WebURL'] != "") { echo '</a>'; } ?>
                  <?php 
            for ($i = 2; $i <= 5; $i++) {
                $var = 'Association'.$i.'ID';
                if ($row_rsSchedules[$var] != 0) { echo '<img src="images/schedules/'.$row_rsSchedules[$var].'.png">';
                } 
                }?><p>Click Logo to visit Association's Website (if available)</p></div>
        <div id="scheduleInfo"><h3><?php echo $row_rsSchedules['Assoc1Acronym']; ?> <?php echo $row_rsSchedules['EventName']; ?></h3><?php if ($row_rsSchedules['EventURL'] != "") { echo '<p><a href="'.$row_rsSchedules['EventURL'].'" target="_blank">Go To Event Website</a></p>'; } ?>
              <p><?php echo date("M j", strtotime($row_rsSchedules['DateFrom'])); ?> - <?php echo date("M j, Y", strtotime($row_rsSchedules['DateTo'])); ?></p>
              <p><?php echo $row_rsSchedules['LocationName']; ?>, <?php echo $row_rsSchedules['Location']; ?></p><p><img src="images/but_event_info.png" width="79" height="26" alt="Event Information" id="Event<?php echo $row_rsSchedules['EventID']; ?>But" /><img src="images/but_venue_info.png" width="79" height="26" alt="Specific Venue Information" id="Venue<?php echo $row_rsSchedules['VenueID']; ?>But" /></p>
              <div class="fullWidthDiv id="<?php echo 'Venue'.$row_rsSchedules['VenueID'].'Div'; ?>">Content for  class "fullWidthDiv" Goes Here</div>
              <div class="fullWidthDiv id="<?php echo 'Event'.$row_rsSchedules['EventID'].'Div'; ?>">Content for  class "fullWidthDiv" Goes Here</div>
        </div>
        <br class="clearFloat" />
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <?php } while ($row_rsSchedules = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSchedules)); ?>
```

I don't even know where to start.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: for achieveing what you want, the html is not clear so you can use jquery' click handlers , live and then toggleclass , show and hide functions to achieve the same, if you can provide your html we can write the exact code, but i have provided some psuedo code kind of stuff where you can get starting...let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
<A ID="categoryContainerToggle" CLASS="standardLink">Hide</A>&nbsp;</TD>


Toggle the changes base on your event 23EventBut

$("#categoryContainerToggle").click(function() {            
        if ($('a#categoryContainerToggle').text()== showText) {
            $('a#categoryContainerToggle').text("Your Hide text here base on your id");
        }else {
            $('a#categoryContainerToggle').text("Your show text here base on your id");
        }           
        $("#categoryContainer").toggle();           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

as they are dynamically added elements you need to use jquery live

```
 $('#buttondiv').live('click', function() {
    $('#23VenueBut').show();
    $('#23EventBut').show();
    $(this).removeClass('oldclass').addClass('newClass')
    });
```

maintain one class with one image and one more class with another hide details image you wanted and add and remove class dynamicall

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `id` attributes are not valid. IDs are not supposed to start with numbers.

You can use `.toggle()` function for this

```
$("#yourbuttonid").toggle(function(){
   $("#venuediv").show();
   $("#eventdiv").show();
   $(this).attr("src", "new image source");
},
function(){
   $("#venuediv").hide();
   $("#eventdiv").hide();
   $(this).attr("src", "old image source");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your code should end up looking something like.. 

$('#23VenueBut').live("click", function(e){
    $('#23VenueDiv').toggle();
    $(this).text(if($(this).css('display') == 'none') ? "Show Venue" : "Hide Venue");
});
```

Comment: I changed that. It was an example, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this very simple.  As it seems that you can multiple event descriptions on the page at once, you may want to attach a class, "event"/"venue" to the appropriate buttons, also add 'hidden' class to them all at first since I think they all start off hidden, then this JS:

```
$(".event.hidden").click(function () {
   $(this).siblings("div").show();
   $(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown').text('Hide Event');
});
$(".event.shown").click(function () {
   $(this).siblings("div").hide();
   $(this).removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden').text('Event Details');
});
```

It seems like the button might not be the sibling of the div, though, but you can parse the right id from the given ID:

```
//In the 'click' functions:
var div_id = this.id.replace(/But/, 'Div');
$("#" + div_id).show(); // or .hide(), as appropriate.
```

Comment: The buttons actually are not hidden.  It is the div that is hidden.

Comment: Not sure how to add the secondary class ".hidden/.shown" to the same button that already has a class of ".event"

Comment: On the line `<div class="fullWidthDiv id="<?php echo 'Event'.$row_rsSchedules['EventID'].'Div'; ?>">` you can probably just also add the initial class "hidden" or "shown" depending on if you want them to start hidden, shown, etc.  The buttons are not hidden or shown, the classes are merely there to indicate whether the div is hidden or shown.  You can also use .data(), it is a bit cleaner.