# JQuery show/hide problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I asked this question yesterday got a pretty good answer but can't figure out how to repost new code to get an answer to another question about the same code.  I have buttons that I want to show/hide divs with information about a particular event/venue.

Here is the button html:

```
<img class="event" src="images/but_event_info.png" width="79" height="26" alt="Event Information" id="Event<?php echo $row_rsSchedules['EventID']; ?>But" /><img class="venue" src="images/but_venue_info.png" width="79" height="26" alt="Specific Venue Information" id="Venue<?php echo $row_rsSchedules['VenueID']; ?>But" /></p>
```

And the divs that I want to show:

```
<div class="VenueInfo" id="<?php echo 'Venue'.$row_rsSchedules['VenueID'].'Div'; ?>">Venue Info for <?php echo $row_rsSchedules['VenueID']; ?></div>
<div class="EventInfo" id="<?php echo 'Event'.$row_rsSchedules['EventID'].'Div'; ?>">Event Info for <?php echo $row_rsSchedules['EventID']; ?></div>
```

Here is the jquery code to show/hide the divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".event.hidden").click(function () {
    var div_id = this.id.replace(/But/, 'Div');
$("#" + div_id).show('fast', 'linear'); 
   //$(this).siblings("div").show();
   $(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown').text('Hide Event');
});
$(".event.shown").click(function () {
   var div_id = this.id.replace(/But/, 'Div');
 $("#" + div_id).hide('fast', 'linear'); 
   //$(this).siblings("div").hide();
   $(this).removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden').text('Event Details');
});

});
</script>
```

The answer was given to me at [jquery show()/Hide() dynamically named elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406116/jquery-show-hide-dynamically-named-elements)

The answer that tandu gave was:
jQuery makes this very simple. As it seems that you can multiple event descriptions on the page at once, you may want to attach a class, "event"/"venue" to the appropriate buttons, also add 'hidden' class to them all at first since I think they all start off hidden, then this JS:

I simply added style settings like so:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.VenueInfo {
 display: none;
}
.EventInfo {
 display: none;
}
.event {
 display: inline;
}

.event {
 display: inline;
}
</style>
```

Pardon me for the fact that I don't know how to repost new code after I have made changes to the same question.  Every time I have posted a question, I get answers and then never a response after I have made changes.

I thank you for you help in advance.

Comment: I am a bit lost as to what the question is.  Are the divs not showing, are the not hidden when the site starts up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking, I guess you are having problems with showing the divs again, so change to

```
display: block;
```

your current

```
 display: inline;
```

**Edit:** and  also you need to name your CSS classes accordingly to the classes you are adding/removing with Jquery

so your css should have

```
.show{ display: block;}
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Comment: What I was having a problem with is that tandu had indicated that I should add a class - hidden to the buttons as well and I don't know what he was talking about.  The trigger is .event.hidden or .event.shown.  How do I add the secondary class to it.

Comment: The div was not the problem.  If I change the trigger to .event, it will show the div just fine.  The inline was for the button

Comment: read the edit, right now your problem is that you are calling addClass('shown') and .shown is not defined also the hidden class

Comment: The javascript looks pretty ugly can you specify better what you are trying to achive.  When I press the button what you want to happen, change VenueInfo to  EventInfo and viceversa?

Comment: Ok, I have defined .shown and .hidden as stated, but the initial click won't fire because the class of the button is just "event".  How do I add the secondary class on the initial load, so that the script will fire. i.e. <img class="event" src="images/but_event_info.png" width="79" height="26" alt="Event Information" id="Event<?php echo $row_rsSchedules['EventID']; ?>But" />

If the class is set to just "event" then it won't fire.  I don't know how to declare another class for the same element.

Comment: This is probably so stupidly easy, it is just flying right over my head.

Comment: Ok but don't tell me in code, tell me in words what you want.  You'll see how easy it is

Comment: I want the button with the class="event" to show the eventInfo div, with the ID's provided in the sample in my initial question, and change the button source to the hide button image. when I click the hide event button, I want it to hide the same div it just opened.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  class="event hidden" seemed to do the trick in the image tag

Comment: Ohh I see now, that's not for newbies stuff, your question to add more classes is very simple though.  <img class="event myOtherClass otherClass" src.....>

Comment: It may be handy for you in the future:  .hidden{display:none;} addClass('hidden') ---> can be simpler to just call the hide() function, or show(). e.g. $(this).hide()

Comment: I have it working on the show() portion, it does exactly what I want, but it will not fire the hide() portion, even though when I look at the generated source in Firebug, it shows the correct class of class="event shown".  When I click it, it does nothing.  URL is http://www.randykrohn.com/schedules.php?Param=all

Comment: I mean delete the line $(document).ready(function() {  and of course the closing one

Comment: I don't quite understand?  I moved all of that outside the document ready and it now doesn't work?

Comment: I've tested the code and it's working, put it back again inside docready, I'm going to see other thing

Comment: Now that's a problem! I pasted the show code into the firebug console and works.  So my advise is to post the javascript and tell that your functions work but after triggering the first click event which is hide, you can't trigger the show.

Comment: Should I post that in another question, or here in the comments

Comment: Another question, no one will read all this, I'm sure you'll get an answer fast.

Comment: Thank you Eric.  I really appreciate your help. Most of the time it only takes one time to figure something out for me and it is in the memory vault.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll be looking forward the answers to that post.